# Is there a way to make Atom highlight the entire soft-wrapped line?

Tags: css, ide, editor, atom-editor, text-editor

I would like not just the screen line to be highlighted, but the whole soft-wrapped line. See the screenshot below for the current behaviour. Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

The closest thing I could find is [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8549) from 2015, which suggests it is impossible.

[image: Screenshot]